# Web Essentials 2013 markdown editor - image paths

Tags: web-essentials

I haven't been able to find much/any documentation on the functionality of this feature of web essentials 2013.

Is it possible to use relative image paths with the web essentials markdown preview?   Also, what about linking from one markdown file to another - any support for that?

Answer (score 4):

1. The [Markdown functionality](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/master/EditorExtensions/Margin/MarkdownMargin.cs) in Web Essentials 2013 is provided via the [MarkdownSharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)  library so any support for image paths etc will be according to MarkdownSharp's implementation, which is the same as the support you get here on StackOverflow.

   You can certainly specify a relative path to an image (however the preview pane in Visual Studio 2013 won't be able to show it):

   `![a lazy cat](img/cat.jpg)`

   The reason the image won't show in the Preview in VS is because the embedded WebBrowser used to show the preview, doesn't actually render the saved .html file, but just renders the generated HTML from a string, so it's not relative to the source .md file... See the `StartCompiler` method in the code.
2. The [Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) doesn't have a special syntax for linking from one page to another (aka "wiki links").

The source code for Web Essentials 2013 is on GitHub: [github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013)